# Is there a "name" for the matrix $xx^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

The product $x^Tx$ is called the inner product. Is there a name for the matrix $xx^T$? I want to be able to read about it but I don't know what to search on.

Comment: $x y^T$ is called the "outer product" of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: It's what you would guess first; $xy^T$ is called the outer product.

Answer (score 0):

As already said in comments, it is the "outer product" of $x$ by itself:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product